# Java Parsing XML multilevel Using Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, twitter

Hello I'm trying to parse the following XML code, and I need only one Value of polarity, in that case I would need N+, but instead I get 3 times the N+ value.

```
<tweet>
  <tweetid>----</tweetid>
  <user>----</user>
  <date>2011-12-02T02:33:37</date>
  <lang>es</lang>
  <sentiments>
  <polarity><value>N+</value><type>AGREEMENT</type></polarity>
  <polarity><entity>Sinde</entity><value>N+</value><type>AGREEMENT</type></polarity>
  <polarity><entity>SGAE</entity><value>N+</value><type>AGREEMENT</type></polarity>
  </sentiments>
  <topics>
   <topic>política</topic>
   <topic>economía</topic>
  </topics>
 </tweet>
 <tweet>
```

And I am using this code:

```
String expression3 = "/tweets/tweet/sentiments/polarity/value[1]";
NodeList nodeList3 = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression3).evaluate(doc,    XPathConstants.NODESET); 
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            System.out.println(j + "--" +nodeList3.item(j).getFirstChild().toString());
        }
```

But I get the following output.

```
0--[#text: N+]
1--[#text: N+]
2--[#text: N+]
```

How can I get only one using the XPath? Because when I build my out.txt I need only one of those polarity values, because in every tweet there is only one value, and because of this,  all the tweets get messed up. I've been trying different expression but i don't get it,

Thank you.

Comment: I put polarity[1]/value instead of polarity/value[1] , and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the expression "/tweets/tweet/sentiments/polarity/value[1]" you are saying "give mi the first node called value, of every node called polarity", if you want to get the value node of the first polarity node try with /tweets/tweet/sentiments/polarity[1]/value